# How do I specify that Cargo should build binaries only on a certain target?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Cargo project set up with a library and a binary. The library is meant to be used on many platforms, including Android, while the binary is only meant to be used on Linux. As such, the binary contains a bunch of Linux-specific code that does not compile when I target Android. Is there a way to specify (without using features) that the binary should only be compiled on Linux?

I tried putting `#![cfg(target_os = "linux")]` in the `main.rs` of my binary, but then I got this error:

```
error[E0601]: `main` function not found in crate `server`
  --> src/bin/server/main.rs:1:1
   |
1  | / #![cfg(target_os = "linux")]
2  | |
3  | | use anyhow::{self, Context};
4  | | 
...  |
36 | |     }
37 | | }
   | |_^ consider adding a `main` function to `src/bin/server/main.rs`
```

Comment: Please refer to the compilation options section in following link:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html>

Please check if that helps

Comment: Can we set a build.target inside of a [[bin]] block in cargo config?  But it's overridden if you use --target.  What does your config look like now?

Comment: Make the binary a sub-crate requiring the library?  This might work, but does seem like a hack.  Good luck!

Comment: you do it correctly it just complains that in your main rust file there's no mail function. how do you expect a binary to work without a main function?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. The official Rust docs do not seem to mention how to solve it. But I found a solution.

The trick is to specify two `main()` functions in the file `main.rs`. The first one contains the code you want to execute when you are on Linux. The second one remains empty. With the help of conditional compilation, you tell the compiler which of the two `main()` functions to compile.

```rust
// within main.rs

#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
fn main() {
    // Your Linux-specific code goes here...
}

#[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))]
fn main() {} // remains empty for all other OS
```

If you have OS-specific imports or other code at the top-level, just wrap it inside a module and use conditional compilation for it as well.

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
mod linux {
    use anyhow::{self, Context};
    // ...
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I've added an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/103336) to Rust's issue tracker about this problem. At least, I hope that the docs and compiler error message will be improved for the conditional compilation of binaries.

Comment: It seems like it's documented here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html

Answer (score -3):

The below link has related information that should help you in terms of target selection and selective compilation https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html#target-selection